# React Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Card extends Component {
  state = {
    toggled: false
  };
  onClick() {
    this.setState({ toggled: !this.state.toggled });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.toggled && <p>Hello World </p>}
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Toggle Card</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a simple button that toggles a state and renders a `<p>` tag, I'm getting an error code of

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

when button is pressed

Comment: in your constructor remember to bind your `onClick`  -> `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)`

Comment: doesn't babel implicity handle this behind the scenes? (nevermind, it just creates a constructor but not bind(this))

Comment: @VincentTang nope

Comment: @VincentTang  No, but you might find this useful. https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator  Arrow functions like pointed out can be used, but remember an arrow function is like doing a bind every time, for things like `onClick` it's not really an issue, but if you was calling a method multiple times in a loop or wanting to pass the function around ad-hoc, bind might be better.

Comment: when would you pass a method adhoc in React though? I can see this being useful in vanillaJS though

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your function.

**Try this:**

```
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ toggled: !this.state.toggled });
  }
```

you need arrow function because you want to access `this` property, which refers to the current class.

Arrow functions means that `this` will not refer to the context of your function but to the context of the class.

Another option is to bind your function in constructor

```
constructor(){
   this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I feel silly for forgetting that, thanks for the reminder

Comment: No problem at all!